# Looping while in Java

Tags: java, loops, nested

Consider my codes are below :

```
int number = 0;
while ((number >=0.5) && (number <= 27.5)) {
    if (number % 1.25 == 0) {
        number +=0.75;
    } else {
        number++;
    }
}
}
```

my question is what is the problem in the codes above?
and if i want to print out the result, the variable number should has the following number of 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 during the process of looping. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

It will never enter the loop because 0 is not >= 0.5

It's not at all clear why you are dealing with quantities such as 0.5, 1.25, 27.5, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? To print the numbers 6 to 28 doesn't need any of those fractional values.

Comment: yeaaa…i found out that something wrong with the code, so do you have any idea about the code above?and what value should assign to variable "number" so that in the result it will print the value  6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 during the process of looping.
if you have any idea, please share.thnx

Comment: your code never prints anything, you have no print statments

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the purpose of your code for others to figure out what is the problem with it.

The issues I see are:

Your while loop would never start because the initial assignment for "number" is out of range.

Also, I see you increment "number" by 1, so your "% 1.25" will never execute.

If you just need to loop from 6 to 28 using the code similar to yours, should be something like this:

```
int number = 6;
while (number < 29) {
  System.out.println(number);
  number++;
}
```

Comment: so, what value should be assigned to variable "number"?
in order to execute %1.25, what should be added?
if you have any idea, please share. thnx

Comment: It depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve in your code. If you just need to increment by 0.25 instead of 1, then you do `number += 0.25` instead of `number++`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like ...

```
int number = 5;
while ((number >=5) && (number <= 27.5)) {
  System.out.println(""+number++);
}
```